# Critical error during OpenCms initialization: Unable to read the OpenCms XML configuratio

Tags: tomcat, jboss, opencms

I have migrated my opencms from jboss to Tomcat Server. I have in total 4 tomcat server. On 2 server it is working completely fine and on 2 it is giving the following error.

'''2022-09-15 04:41:42,620 SEVERE [Username:] [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]] (org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom) Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=500, location=/opencms-errorhandler/system/handler/handle500.html]
org.opencms.main.CmsInitException: Critical error during OpenCms initialization: Unable to read the OpenCms XML configuration.
at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.getInstance(OpenCmsCore.java:268)
at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsServletErrorHandler.doGet(OpenCmsServletErrorHandler.java:79)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:349)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)'''

The configuration of all 4 tomcat server are same so no idea about how it is working on 5 server and on 5 giving error.

Comment: Please check the XML configuration files under /config/ for correct syntax. Have you taken a look at the catalina.out log file from Tomcat?

Comment: Yes no issue in catalina and server.xml on tomcat. Just the above error of failing to initialize. It is working on 4 and on 2 it is failing even though they all have same configuration

Comment: Any error messages in /logs/opencms.log?